# iOS: block copied and added to mutable array, do I need to release them when empty the array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

So if I have:

```
SomeBlock myBlock = ^(){};
[self.mutableArray addObject: [myBlock copy] ];
```

later if I need to:

```
[self.mutableArray removeAllObjects];
```

then should I first go through all the blocks in the array and release each of them?

Thanks

Edit:

I am not using ARC, and I saw somewhere when I add a block to array I need to copy it, that's why I do `[block copy]` when I add it to array, thus I thought that I should release them before I remove all objects from the array.

Comment: what does instrument show? any leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you are *not* using ARC (the question would not be interesting then).

In your code, you do need to send `release` to all of your blocks:: although `NSArray` retains objects placed into it, and releases objects when the array itself is released, the objects that you add already have a retain count of `1`, because `copy` method gives you an object with a retain count of `1`. That is why you need to follow `copy` with `autorelease` before adding your block to the array, like this:

```
[self.mutableArray addObject: [[myBlock copy] autorelease]];
```

Comment: So if I do `[[myBlock copy] autorelease]` then I can just do `[self.mutableArray removeAllObjects]` without releasing each element of it?

Comment: @hzxu Yes, that is correct: `autorelease` would take care of the initial reference count of `1` given to the copied block, while the `NSArray` would take care of retaining the block while it's inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get the ownership of any object, it is yours duty to release it otherwise a memory leak will happen.

> If you don't release your pointer to that object, it will be a leak.
>   When you release the array, it will call release on all of the objects
>   that it holds, since it called retain previously.

For ARC, it will be in autorelease so you need to release yourself.